# Script takes more time for loading in JMeter GUI

Tags: jmeter

We have recorded a script in JMeter where it captures the photo image of webcam in an online exam. Due to this we get more requests in JMeter and file size of jmx file is 20mb. When we save it and reopen the script it takes nearly 1 hour to open the script

How to solve this issue?

Comment: am using jmeter 5.4 version

Answer (score 0):

If you have a logical operation consisting of large number of requests with large bodies the only workaround I can think of is:

1. Moving these requests to external .jmx scripts as [Test Fragments](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment)
2. Link these Test Fragments into the "main" .jmx script using [Include Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller)

More information: [How to Manage Large JMeter Scripts With JMeter Test Fragments](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-manage-large-jmeter-scripts-jmeter-test-fragments)